# What do you do when you want to commit a hunk and git thinks you're changing another hunk of text?

Tags: json, git

I'm editing a json configuration file, and much of it is similar.  I'd like to edit it in hunks, since I was overly eager and made more than one change to my working directory.

I removed the configurations for two pages.

I'd prefer to add the changes to the index (the stage) separately in two separate commits, by adding hunks to them; however....

When I do go to do this; git ends up confusing the lines I remove with lines from the second page's configuration using `git add -p config.js` and it ends up in several hunks, looking something like this:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -665,25 +665,30 @@ var handlebarTemplateGen = function(loadedContent, filePathsArray) {
                  }
                  ]
        },
+       /*BEGIN: Controller*/
        {
-         "outputfile":"../../someplace.org/removeMe1.html",
+         "outputfile":"../../someplace.org/removeMe2.html",
          "processingOrder": [ 
                  { 
                   "view":"views/common/empty.view",
                   "template":"HeadStart.mustache"
                  },
+                 /*
                  {
-                  "view":"views/removeMe1/meta.view",
+                  "view":"views/removeMe2/meta.view",
                   "template":"meta.mustache"
                  },
+                 */
                  {
-                  "view":"views/removeMe1/HeadEnd.view",
+                  "view":"views/removeMe2/HeadEnd.view",
                   "template":"HeadEnd.mustache"
                  },
+                 /*
                  {
                   "view":"views/common/empty.view",
                   "template":"SocialMediaShareScripts.mustache"
                  },
+                 */
                  {
                    "view":"views/index/navbar.view",
                    "template":"navbar.mustache"
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

...and I've tried about everything, but I can't seem to get just the changes to removeMe1 on the stage without also having the removeMe2 changes come along for the ride.

I tried following the instructions about counting lines when editing manually hunks in [joaquin's post](http://joaquin.windmuller.ca/2011/11/16/selectively-select-changes-to-commit-with-git-or-imma-edit-your-hunk) here, but when I get to the last one that states that I can't remove the references lines I start to have an issue, since I want to remove a block of code and set the reference lines to `-` (which I understand you have to replace, not just type in)

There was also [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tqMjJeyKpw) that was helpful on learning this here, but it didn't really fix my issue; it simply told me about how lines should be counted.

I frequently get the "patch does not apply" error when doing this as well, usually because I turned a reference line into a `-` line.

Is there a way to split this by spiting hunks into separate commits, or is it just a bad idea to store json config files in git?

Comment: You want the commenting, but not the replacement of `removeMe1` with `removeMe2`?

Comment: @hobbs I put the comment there to try to make git not get confused. (desperation really)

Comment: if you want to delete them then delete them from the file, git will have less things to be confused about. If not, then *I'm* confused and I don't know what you're asking :)

Comment: @hobbs I have two sets of lines in a json file.  They both start and end with a curly bracket, and occupy two separate ranges of lines which do not overlap.   I have removed them both from the same file in my working copy.  I wish to commit these to the repository in separate distinct commits, so that when someone looks at the changeset from each commit, on that file, they can go...oh look he removed the removeMe1 block from the file; and then a commit later they can go, oh look he removed the removeMe2 block from the same file.  At the moment I am unable to add just the changes from removeMe1

Comment: @hobbs did that help?

Comment: what you're showing from `git add -p` doesn't seem consistent with that though — it should just show a lot of `-` lines if that stuff was removed in the working tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92775/discussion-between-hobbs-and-leeand00).